# Socket IO Client in GatsbyJS doesn't work

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, socket.io, gatsby

Hello friends I?m new here and I found with a hard issue, I have used Socket IO Client in react js without any problem, the same syntax  i used with Gatsby and I find this problem. My node js server doesn't detect when a new client has joined.

This my script.

React JS Component (Works)

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import './App.css';

// socket
import socketIOClient from 'socket.io-client';

const socketEndPoint = 'http://localhost:32/';

const ioSocket = socketIOClient(socketEndPoint); 

// nameSpace: public_chat
const ns= 'public_chat';
const salaSocket = socketIOClient(socketEndPoint + ns)
const messageKey = 'test_message'; // Message id

function App() {
  function sendMessage(){
    salaSocket.emit(messageKey, 'Prueba de mensaje desde el cliente: '+Math.random())
  }

  function recepMessage(){
    salaSocket.on(messageKey, (received) => {
      alert('Message: '+ received)
    })
  }

  useEffect(() => recepMessage() , [])

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button style={{marginTop: '50', padding: '10px'}} onClick={sendMessage}>
        Send message
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

With GatsbyJS Component (not working)

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react'
import './Chat.scss'
import { Button } from '@material-ui/core'
import socketIOClient from 'socket.io-client'

const socketEndPoint = 'http://localhost:32'
const sala = 'public_chat'
const salaSocket = socketIOClient(socketEndPoint + sala)
const messageKey = 'test_message'

function Chat() {
    function initSocket() {
        salaSocket.on(messageKey, received => alert('Message received: '+ received))
    }
    function sendMessage() {
        salaSocket.emit(messageKey, `Send a message to server`)
    }
    useEffect(() => {
        initSocket()
    }, [])
    return(
        <div className='chat'>
            <Button onClick={sendMessage}>send</Button>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Chat
```

As you see, both have the same script or the same logic about socket io usage, but I don't know why in react works and gatsbyjs not. Maybe is a bug or what's the problem?

Server (No problem)

```
const express = require('express')
const http = require('http')
const socketIo = require('socket.io')
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 32
const app = express()

const server = http.createServer(app)
const io = socketIo(server, {origins: '*:*'})

app.get('/', (req, res) => res.sendFile(`${__dirname}/index.html`))
server.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Socket runing at port: ${PORT}`))

const sala = io.of('public_chat')
const messageKey = 'test_message'
sala.on('connection', socket => {
    console.log('New user connected', socket.id)
    socket.on(messageKey, data => {
        console.log('received: ', data)
        sala.emit(messageKey, data)
    })
})
```

Thanks for your support :)

Answer (score 2):

I solved this, the issue was the package version on client side I changed to "2.2" because the previous "2.3" wasn't working with my logic, it works now :D

Comment: Do you have any repo to have an example?

Comment: Yep, this also worked for me. The socket.io version running on the server needed to match the one that was running in Gatsby. Even though I installed the up to date socket.io-client (3.0.3), it was ignored and the Gatsby one was used (version 2.3.0).